# Fullcalendar eventClick removeEvent with popup is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Hi I have made bootstrap popup modal on eventClick fullcalndar with remove button.
(popup modal, button click is working)
However, when Remove button is clicked, I added to code removeEvent with event id. 
but event is not disappear. Since I don't have experiences of jquery, javascript, css, fullcalendar,etc. It swallows huge amount of time to figure out. 
I add code here, and really appreciated if someone point me out what I did wrong.

```
The expected behavior :
    1) Click the existing event : eventClick
    2) Popup modal appears with close, remove button
    3) Click the Remove button on popup modal
    4) the clicked event is disappear
```

and my code here. I have tried 2 different ways - Case 1, Case 2

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">Are you sure remove the event?</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="revButton" data-dismiss="modal">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Case 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
…..

    eventClick: function(event, delta) {

        //these are working
        $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
        $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
        $('#fullCalModal').modal();

        // [Case 1] notting happen, event is not disappered(deleted) , why?
        $("revButton").click(function() {  // [Solved] This was the problem, it should be #revButton
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id); //external event, therefore using event._id
        });
    }

….
}
```

**Behavior of Case 1: Expected behavior 1) 2) 3) working but 4) is not working**

Case 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
…..

    eventClick: function(event, delta) {

        //these are working
        $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
        $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
        $('#fullCalModal').modal();

        // [Case 2] why it deletes before modal popup (before press remove button)?
        // why .click() is not working?
        $("#revButton").click(removeRevent(event._id));  //external event, therefore using event._id
    }

….
}

function removeRevent(id){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
}
```

**Behavior of Case 2: Expected behavior 1) -> 2) -> 4) -> 3)**

but I want to the action of sequence 1) -> 2)  -> 3) -> 4)

```
Expected behavior
1) Click the existing event : eventClick   
2) Popup modal appears with close, remove button 
3) Click the Remove button on popup modal
4) The clicked event is disappear
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle example of you problem so that we can help you better....

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap for modal popup and that has many related .js links..and my code using external events , so I need to add all the related code to reproduce the behavior on jsfiddle. I have tried to create jsfiddle but it doesn't work and I used too much time for only making jsfiddle what I felt completely extra work plus my own struggle to fix this code for several days. so I expect someone who knows about this kind code very well and point about on my code without reproducing on jsfiddle

Comment: @user1915570 your code (CASE 1) actually works fine, you just have a typo as `$("revButton")` should be `$("#revButton")`. [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pytv319a/). If your code still isn't working... please update.

Comment: Yes, I also just found that mistake. How could I miss it!! if you write it for an answer, I can select it for you.

Comment: @user1915570 I'm just voting to close. Questions caused by typographical error are considered off-topic. Glad to help!